# Stata constrained regression with constraint greater than zero

Tags: stata

Can you do a constrained regression in Stata with the following constraints:

```
var1 + var2 + ... = 1

var1, var2,... > 0
```

The regression works well with constraint 1, but drops constraint 2 and states:

> (note: constraint number 2 caused error r(111))

Is there any way around this?

Comment: This question needs to show the exact syntax you used.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the `constraint` command. `help constraint` makes no mention of inequalities, only of equalities, so you need a different approach.

A quick search gives the following results which seem relevant to your case:

http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2011-06/msg00086.html

http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/regression-with-interval-constraints/

http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/linear-regression-with-interval-constraints/

Note: it is good practice to post the code you're using with results, or a minimal example that reproduces your problem. In the long-run, it makes things easier for everyone.

Comment: No "probably" here; `constraint` only deals with linear constraints. If any parameters must be positive, you need a parameterisation in terms of their logarithms, to ensure that the reverse transformation yields a satisfactory number.